# Перебор значений из текстового документа

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Не получается заставить этот элемент подставлять вместо $value ('user_id' => $value) - ID из списка user_id.txt

Когда он отправляет сообщение то подставляет только последний ID из документа. (тем самым сообщение приходит только одному пользователю, а не всем указанным в списке)

Где я налажал?

```
$idsFile = __DIR__ . '/user_id.txt';
$idsStr = file_get_contents($idsFile);
$ids = array_filter(explode("\n", $idsStr));

foreach ($ids as $value) {} 

    if($copy == "post") {$messages_send = array( 

            'message' => "Привет",
            'user_id' => $value,
            'access_token' => $access_token, 
            'v' => '5.0');

        $get_params = http_build_query($messages_send); 
        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params); 
    }
```

ID в списке (выглядит так)

```
14143596
29674938
13492246
33994725
```

Comment: что там у вас в `print_r($ids)` то находится?

Comment: Выдает Array (если я правильно понял вопрос)

Comment: А суть его разделять список ID (вид строк добавил в описание темы) по символу

Comment: Первые три строки можно заменить на `$ids = file( __DIR__ .'/user_id.txt');` и все в теории должно сработать

Comment: @Let'ssayPie не отправляет вообще сообщения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы пустой цикл гоняете, последнее значение $value вам и достаётся, скобку закрывающую не там поставили у цикла foreach

Comment: Вы про имеете виду {}?

Comment: да, эту скобку } поставьте в самый конец

Comment: Ура, примите мою искреннюю благодарность

Comment: :) бывает, банальная невнимательность, если у вас много сообщений, то попробуйте на мультикурл переделать, отправка в несколько раз быстрее будет

Comment: @ТимофейКучербаев, все равно рекомендую мой подход, с ныне исправленным циклом

Comment: @Let'ssayPie сейчас попробовал, все работает, так что оставлю ваш вариант =) Большое спасибо за помощь